# Swift PHP post request set global variable from task

Tags: ios, swift, closures, global-variables

I successfully retrieve data from database by using post request. (I don't want to use get request cuz I want to send a verification to php.) Don't worry about the php part, it should be fine.

```
import UIKit

class mainPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    var values:NSArray = []

    @IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        Open.target = self.revealViewController()
        Open.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        get()

    }
    func get(){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.percyteng.com/orbit/getAllpostsTest.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "user=\("ios")"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {

                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let array = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
            self.values = array
        }
        task.resume()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { tableView.reloadData()}
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if values.count > 20{
            return 20
        }
        else{
            return values.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!postCell

        let maindata = values[values.count-1-indexPath.row]
        if maindata["category"] as? String == "Services"{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_services")
        }
        else if maindata["category"] as? String == "exchange"{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_exchange")
        }
        else if maindata["category"] as? String == "Tutors"{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_tutoring")
        }
        else if maindata["category"] as? String == "Sports"{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_sports")
        }
        else if maindata["category"] as? String == "Sublet"{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_sublet")
        }
        else if maindata["category"] as? String == "Events"{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_events")
        }
        else{
            cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named: "tile_carpool")
        }


        if maindata["category"] as? String == "Services" || maindata["category"] as? String == "Tutors" || maindata["category"] as? String == "Events"{
            cell.title.text = maindata["title"] as? String
        }
        else if maindata["category"] as? String == "Sublet" || maindata["category"] as? String == "Rideshare"{
            cell.title.text = maindata["location"] as? String
        }
        else{
            cell.title.text = maindata["item"] as? String
        }


        if maindata["category"] as? String == "Sublet" || maindata["category"] as? String == "Rideshare"{
            cell.location.text = ""
        }
        else{
            cell.location.text = maindata["location"] as? String
        }
        cell.category.text = maindata["category"] as? String
        cell.price.text = maindata["price"] as? String
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }
}
```

So I have a globale variable called values which is a NSArray, and I want to set the value of this array to be the array that I retrieve from database. However, in function get(), the post request acts as another thread and I have to write self.values = array which doesn't change the value of my global variable.

I need that value to organize my tableview in the main array.

Basically, my question is how can I get the value from a closure and set it to a global variable.

Thank you! Let me know if you guys don't understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Use the debugger to add a breakpoint at `self.values = array` and check for the value of `array` when it halts at that position (either in the bottom left view or type  `p dump(array)` in the console). Also I suggest to use `[AnyObject]` instead of `NSArray`.

Comment: Hey, I checked before and at that point, array gives the correct information I want from database. its just nothing gets saved outside of task closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure implicitly retains self, so you are actually modifying that property. But you need to refresh your tableView after the data is retrieved within the closure, either using `reloadCellsAtIndexPath`, `insertCellsAtIndexPath`, or `reloadData`. The latter is the simplest approach, but completely replaces the current state of the table.

Additionally, you are causing a retain cycle in your closure. You should pass in self as a `weak` or `unowned` property to let ARC do its job. For more information on that: http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

Example:

```
func get(){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.percyteng.com/orbit/getAllpostsTest.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "user=\("ios")"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {

            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let array = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
        self.values = array
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
            self.tableView?.reloadData();
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I just edited my code and i do have tableview.reloadData after i did task.resume(). This doesn't really do anything tho.

Comment: @PercyTeng Since the data is delivered asynchronously, nothings gonna happen when you refresh it right after sending the request with `resume`. You need to refresh it when you actually assign the array.

Comment: The thing is, I'm retrieving the data from database to variable array within the task thread, but I want to set it to global variable "values" first and my tableview's values will change according to the value of "values". So the code of assigning array is within that thread but the code of assigning values to tableview is in another thread

Comment: I know what you mean, i should reload tableview data after i assign values to variable since all the tableview data are loaded from the variable "values" but my problem is that my code never assigns any value to variable "values" because "values" is a global variable in the main thread while i get the data i want in another thread which is the post request

Comment: The other thread does not matter, self is still captured within the closure. You are not reloading the data within the closure after setting the values property. You need to do it right after setting self.value, within the closure. You can execute it on the main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [unowned self] in })

Comment: Ya, yesterday I tried to do tableView.reloadData after the line self.values = array within the thread, but it didn't work. Also, is there just no way to assign a global variable value from another thread?

Comment: I think you're misinformed, the thread has access to the same exact variables as the other thread because it is captured in the closure. You just need to set the value and then call reloadData on the main thread. If you want, you can execute both on the main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self in // Code here}`

Comment: How and where would I be able to set the values of variable "values" in the main thread? i retrieve data to the variable "array" in the task thread, but "array" doesn't exist in the main thread. and if i assign value to "values" from "array" in the task thread, it won't get saved in the main thread.

Comment: When you do `self.values = array` it is changing the global one. The fact that it is on a different thread does not matter. However your table view is not being refreshed after this. Right after you set the value within the closure, you must call `reloadData` on the main thread using dispatch_async.

Comment: I edited the code and added         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { tableView.reloadData()}
  } after task.resume(). but is this what u meant tho? how do i call reloadData on the main thread right after i set the value within the closure? i don't get it.

Comment: You added it to the wrong place. You need to add it within the completion handler for URL session.

Comment: I have added a quick example with the change.

Comment: Does that mean I can also do  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
            self.values = array;
        } or not cuz "array" is in another thread at this point? sorry i dont get to access my code right now

Comment: You can do that as well, but that is not an issue. When you entered that thread, it implicitly captured the pointer to `self`. It has access to the same `self` that your main thread points to along with its properties (e.g., `self.values`)

Comment: Thank you that works! except after i do             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                self.values = array
                self.tableView?.reloadData();
            }                      the value of "values" is still not changed in the main thread.

Comment: @SArnab Hi, I know it's been a while and I'm trying to understand the basics of this request again. My question is, when I did this request, is it an asynchronous request that creates another thread? And that's why we are using dispatch to go back to the main thread and update the UI? I also used a completion closure to update the value of my global variable from the result that was passed from the request. I am a bit confused why I need to use both dispatch and completion closure.

Answer (score 1):

You need a completion handler in your `func get()` as you're doing the `dataTaskWithRequest` which is an `Async` call. Try this:

```
func get(finished: (isDone: Bool) -> ()){
//your code
data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                finished(isDone: false)
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            print("response = \(response)")

            let array = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
            self.values = array
        }
}
task.resume()
finished(isDone: true)
}
```

And then in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   get { success in
   if success{
//reload your tableview here
}

}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer but someone else provided me a completion handler to pass data instead of just a boolean variable. Thx tho!